# How to remove section from UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am new to iOS and programming in general and am trying to create my first app. I have searched a while for a solution to this but could not find one. I have a UITableView with cells divided into sections that I would like to enable the user to delete. I had no problem implementing it so that the cells delete, but I want to delete a section when there are zero cells within it, and this is causing me trouble. My numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection methods return the correct amount. My commitEditingStyle method looks like this: (dataTable is a dictionary of type [String : [String]] that I am using to store the information for each cell where the key is the section header and the values are cells in that section.)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        dataTable[Array(dataTable.keys)[indexPath.section]]!.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        if dataTable[Array(dataTable.keys)[indexPath.section]]!.count == 0 {

            dataTable.removeValueForKey(Array(dataTable.keys)[indexPath.section])
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        } else {

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        }

    }

}
```

I believe I have narrowed down what the problem is, but I do not know how to fix it. When I call tableView.deleteSections, I get the error

```
'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows
contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the
number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or
minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that
section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

I believe this is because section 2 is moved up to section 1, section 3 to section 2, etc. when section 1 is removed, but the number of cells in each section is not updated. In my testing I found that this error only occurs if every section after the one deleted does not have the same numbers of cells as the one being deleted (so 1 cell, since the section is only deleted when the number of cells is reduced to zero). I think to fix this I could manually update the number of cells in each section, but I do not know how to do this. Again, the problem is not that I am returning an incorrect value for the number of cells and number of sections. Any help would be great, and thanks in advance.

Comment: can u show how u are populating your cell

Comment: Well its working fine

Comment: @HamzaAnsari What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem so I wanted to share it. For some reason I was assuming the dataTable would keep its order after deleting an object, so every time in my code I called `dataTable.keys` I instead did `dataTable.keys.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two delegate methods to handle section deletion:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
  return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
   if (editingStyle == .Delete) {
   // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)

   self.tableView.beginUpdates()

   self.feedData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row) // also remove an array object if exists.
   self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)

   self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```